# ogr2ogr DXF_FEATURE_LIMIT_PER_BLOCK error

Tags: gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr, dxf

I am trying to convert a DXF to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr

However, I am getting the below error:

```
Limit of 10000 features for block ____ reached.
If you need more, set the DXF_FEATURE_LIMIT_PER_BLOCK
configuration option to the maximum value (or -1 for no limit)
```

How do I go about setting the `DXF_FEATURE_LIMIT_PER_BLOCK` to -1?

Comment: https://gdal.org/user/configoptions.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `DXF_FEATURE_LIMIT_PER_BLOCK` with the `--config` switch.

```
ogr2ogr --config DXF_FEATURE_LIMIT_PER_BLOCK -1
```